# MongoDB Array matching 6 from 10

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection in mongodb with thousand documents like this :

```
{
    "numbers" : [
            31,
            12,
            19,
            41,
            2,
            15
    ],
    "date" : ISODate("2014-06-18T09:37:59.164Z"),
    "string" : "31,12,19,41,2,15",
    "_id" : "Eg38tNEZFtTZTmxjx"
}
```

I also have an match array like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]

How can I query documents that match 6 numbers from the match array;

I know this: db.collection.find({ numbers: { $all: [ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] } });

but this limits me to checking a match array with only 6 numbers, i want the match array be with 10 numbers and only return the documents that have 6 numbers from those 10.

p.s. I can change the form of document if it's needed to add any field to it. To make the match perform faster. I can rewrite the whole database it's not a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. But thank you very mutch :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say your best starting point is investigating the mongodb $where operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

That gives you the opportunity to write a custom function for the comparison.  However, if performance is a concern you may have to revisit your model design to allow for better indexing.

Example code for reducing an array to matches:

```
var numbers = [31,12,19,41,2,15,1,4,3,7,5];
var matchArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function isInList() {
    var reducedNums = numbers.filter(function(num) {
        return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1
    });

    console.log(reducedNums);
}
```

With the `reducedNums` you'll be able to check the length to make sure it's >= 6.

To use that in a query you can do something like:

```
var matchArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function isInList() {
    // `this` contains each object in the mongo query.
    var reducedNums = this.numbers.filter(function(num) {
        return matchArray.indexOf(num) !== -1
    });
    return reducedNums.length >= 6;
}

db.myDocuments.find({ $where: isInList });
```

That code is untested, fyi.